# How can I run a gradle based Libgdx eclipse project in AIDE on Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, aide-ide

Before Gradle was used with libgdx I could just open my Eclipse project in AIDE and everything worked fine. As of libgdx version 1.0 I now use Gradle in Eclipse but I don't know how to get this to work with AIDE.

It's not finding the jar libraries because I get compile errors about unknown libgdx classes.

Do I have to add a local Maven repository or is there another way?

Thanx!

Comment: I'm not sure what AIDE is but I would think you could run 'gradlew eclipse' from the top level command line and that should generate eclipse files. Then if AIDE recognizes eclipse projects it should see your projects at that point.

Comment: it is an android app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en

Comment: did you try 'gradlew eclipse' from the top level folder of your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues, and what worked for me is I started a libgdx project within AIDE (yes it has that function), let it set itself up properly with all the libraries etc in the lib folder, then copied my code into the respective core, android etc folders as appropriate.

It's a bit fiddly, and I'm still not 100% there yet as I'm trying to work off two git branches, one for laptop (with gradle, your original project), and one for AIDE (with all the libraries already in it)

It should at least help you get your project working.

Comment: Thanx, as of the latest release of AIDE I got it working with one of my projects, another one still has problems, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124267/how-to-get-libgdx-gradled-eclipse-project-to-work-on-aide-android-ide-app

Comment: When you said the latest build, was that the one that can now use gradle files? I just received an update today that says it can use gradle files, but haven't tried that theory yet

Comment: @Johan Stolk - I've just tried to use the new AIDE that allegedly has gradle support, which has now broken my previously working AIDE project, and won't work with my gradle based one! Have you had any luck?

Comment: Just fixed my working app again, for me I'd lost my .project and .classpath files as they were in my .gitignore. Creating a new temp libgdx project and copying those two files into mine worked

Comment: Detailed description of that approach (use gradle in Android Studio and eclipse ant project files on mobile device) with example code here: http://deepscorn.blogspot.ru/2016/07/building-and-running-android-studio.html May be helpful